# using packagemanager to uninstall latest kernel?

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, package-management

The last update (I updated 9/1/14) to the kernel broke my boot. I was able to boot into the previous kernel. I think the version that was stable was 3.13.0.34.40 and the update was 3.13.0.35.42--Is there a way to use synaptic package manager to remove the latest update from my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in terminal if your kernel version is not `3.13.0-35-generic` by using `uname -r`
then you can delete latest kernel (3.13.0-35-generic) by using this command from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge 3.13.0-35
```

then update your grub: use this command

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: checked in terminal, using 3.13.0-34-generic. 
Entered next command, got 

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: @KimJongIl Close any terminal, software center, and all update software. it will fix.

Comment: Ah, had package manager open still from getting changelogs. worked, updated grub, gonna reboot soon to check. Thanks for help!

Comment: The thing is, why does it brake. Mine broke as well and I have no clue of what this might be... I thought that could be something related with LVM (kernel modules or something) but I couldn't really pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @rpvilao If you have a problem please ask that as a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). I don't know really what your problem is. thanks

Comment: Totally worked for me through three boots. Auto Update hasn't tried to install it again either. I call success! Thanks again.